# Changing measure based on sheet

Tags: measure, qliksense

Is it possible to make a variable change in your measures based on the sheet that it is used in?

I have in about 15 measures and 3 sheets. The 15 measures need to vary slightly from sheet to sheet, so I wonder if it is possible to do someting like:

```
   sum(

         {<
            ,A={"1"} 
            ,B= 
            ,C=(IF SHEET = SHEET1 THEN {"1"}, IF SHEET = SHEET2 THEN {"2"}) 
            ,D= 
            ,E=  
         >} 

         people)
```

The alternative is to make 3x15 measures which is not very practical.

Comment: Ohh.. I thought I was let to an overflow site specifically for Qlik. Thank you - I will add that immediately.

Comment: That is an occasional misunderstanding, but the Ask a Question Wizard does not change where the question is posted. It only guides you in the question writing process, and sometimes proposes not to ask it on SO specifically. Questions still end up on the same site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi yes you need to use extension for this for example:

```
https://developer.qlik.com/garden/5a0972383a163ae72f86f26b
```

you can check also other from https://developer.qlik.com/
There is no native function for that (it is in qlikview so maybe someday it will be implemented in qliksense too)

Extension which url I shared add trigger on enterSheet so you need to set that this trigger "set variable" for example:

```
Target:
vSheetName

Expression:
'Sheet1'
```